# Error diagnosis help - TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'

Tags: optimization, typeerror

I am a student learning python/pyomo. getting an error message that I do not know why it is not running....

```
model=ConcreteModel()

#DV's

D = needed.index

model.L=Var(domain=NonNegativeIntegers)
model.H=Var(domain=NonNegativeIntegers)
model.UsedL=Var(D, domain=NonNegativeIntegers)
model.UsedH=Var(D, domain=NonNegativeIntegers)
model.RentL=Var(D, domain=NonNegativeIntegers)
model.RentH=Var(D, domain=NonNegativeIntegers)
model.HFL=Var(D, domain=NonNegativeIntegers)


#ObjFct
model.cost=Objective(expr=(7*(model.H*44+model.L*32))+sum([40*model.UsedL[d]+54*(model.UsedH[d]+model.HFL[d])+175*model.RentL[d]+225*model.RentH[d]] for d in D), sense=minimize)

#Constraints
model.heavies=ConstraintList()
model.ownedh=ConstraintList()
model.lights=ConstraintList()
model.lightsused=ConstraintList()

for d in D:
    model.heavies.add(model.UsedH[d]+model.RentH[d] >= needed.loc[d,'Heavies'])
    model.ownedh.add(model.UsedH[d]+model.HFL[d] <= model.H)
    model.lights.add(model.UsedL[d]+model.RentL[d]+model.HFL[d] >= needed.loc[d,'Lights'])
    model.lightsused.add(model.UsedL[d] <= model.L)
    
    
solver = SolverFactory('glpk')
solver.solve(model)

model.display()
```

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[4], line 17
     13 model.HFL=Var(D, domain=NonNegativeIntegers)
     16 #ObjFct
---> 17 model.cost=Objective(expr=(7*(model.H*44+model.L*32))+sum([40*model.UsedL[d]+54*(model.UsedH[d]+model.HFL[d])+175*model.RentL[d]+225*model.RentH[d]] for d in D), sense=minimize)
     19 #Constraints
     20 model.heavies=ConstraintList()

File <__array_function__ internals>:200, in sum(*args, **kwargs)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py:2318, in sum(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims, initial, where)
   2311 if isinstance(a, _gentype):
   2312     # 2018-02-25, 1.15.0
   2313     warnings.warn(
   2314         "Calling np.sum(generator) is deprecated, and in the future will give a different result. "
   2315         "Use np.sum(np.fromiter(generator)) or the python sum builtin instead.",
   2316         DeprecationWarning, stacklevel=3)
-> 2318     res = _sum_(a)
   2319     if out is not None:
   2320         out[...] = res

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
```

not sure, tried looking for typos and messing around with variables in objective function.
Any help is appreciated

I have tried adding variables and not sure how to change ti make things both integers or lists or what to do....